# With Xcode how can I export and share an app with a team member in the simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

So I have a teammate/client I need to share an app I'm developing. 
They have android and a Mac Desktop so it would be shared through the Simulator only.

I've tried the archive app and there seems to be no way to get this work with the .ipa file which is generated.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: Its possible. Checkout [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io/) You can share your simulator build and your client can check it out through browsers. Apparently they're installing your app to their simulators. So you need to do a little investigation, how they can install it on simulator manually. EachSpace has a tutorial, check out 4th point on how you can install a build to simulator: [Preview an App using Apple XCode simulator](http://support.eachscape.com/customer/portal/articles/1769555-preview-an-ios-app-using-xcode-simulator)

Comment: Another one here: [New features in Xcode 8.2 Simulator](https://medium.com/xebia/new-features-in-xcode-8-2-simulator-fc64a4014a5f) So specifically, you can share the build that's built (.app) for simulator environment to your client, and they can simply drag and drop on iOS simulator, and its installed.

Answer (score 1):

#### What generates the .app

You will need to have previously built the app for the intended target. The "Product" option in the top menu bar includes a couple of ways to trigger this including: "Build for" of "Destination".

#### Where is the .app?

The `yourApp.app` you are looking for is stored in: `<<YOURUSERHOME>>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<<YOURAPPNAME-UID>>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator`

#### Easier way to locate

1. Open you app in XCODE
2. Browse the file tree in the left sidebar
3. Expand the "Products" directory
4. Right click the `.app` file you want to share, and select "Show In Finder"

Answer (score 0):

Share the source code, then run the app in Xcode. Voila, it is now in the Simulator. They have to install Xcode anyway to get the Simulator so there really isn't any extra work involved other than building the app.

The .ipa is built for iOS devices and cannot run in the Simulator. I suppose you could transfer the binary to another simulator and get it to work, but I have not heard of anyone doing it that way and, frankly, it seems like potentially more work than "clone this git repo, load the project/workspace in Xcode, click the triangle button and wait a bit."

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is you can just generate the `.app` file. But how you can run it on a simulator (applies only if Xcode 8.2 or above isn't installed), I really don't have the idea. If you want to have your `.app` generated, follow this:

1. Connect any iPhone with your mac
2. Open your project in Xcode
3. Wait for the setup (processing symbol files, blah, blah) to be completed
4. Run your project in that iPhone once
5. Now just build your project while the iPhone is connected
6. Search for the **Product** group (or, folder) and expand it
7. You will see a file (maybe more) named as your target (project name)
8. Right click on that file and select ***show in finder***. And voila, you have your `.app` file

Comment: so 8.2 kills this ability?

Comment: No. What I meant to say is _you can run it on a simulator on Xcode 8.2 or above_ by dragging the `.app` file. But how you can achieve this with the previous versions isn't known to me. You can have a good understanding [here](https://medium.com/xebia/new-features-in-xcode-8-2-simulator-fc64a4014a5f#.9fc62dwed)

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is not going to work. You can not share the .ipa file for someone else to install it on an iPhone simulator.

Comment: I've seen people share the .app file contained in the .ipa file. I was able to do it once but not reproduce the steps.

Comment: FAKE NEWS! This is absolutely possible. .ipa is for real devices and .app is for sims. https://forum.katalon.com/t/ipa-vs-app-files-differences-for-ios-mobile-testing-on-simulator/24626